# Filter a Content Query Web Part using the values of another web part on the same page

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts

I have a Content Query Web Part on my page that rolls up all the contacts lists from all the sub-webs in my site collection.  this works fine.  I'd like to be able dynamically filter the contacts rollup by having the user click on a list of leters of the aphhabet at the top of the page.  click A and see the contacts that start with A, etc...

I'm plopping various filter web parts on the page, but don't see how to filter the results of the CQWP.  The connections menu is not much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the OOB filter webparts or CQWP like that.

What you can do is extend the CQWP and add some functionality to it - take a look at [Enhanced Content Query Web Part](http://www.codeplex.com/ECQWP) over at codeplex.com for inspiration.

Then send the clicked letter to the QueryString and have your extended CQWP read the filter value from the querystring - this would perform really well

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this sort of thing requires some development.  Here's one source:

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2008/02/18/Subclassing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-Adding-Dynamic-Filtering.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i would not recommend you to use a cqwp....instead try using a dataview web part it allows you to filter the content using querystring parameters without coding.